# CSS based growing line will not show on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, draw

I have (tried) to create a timeline effect with a scrolling / growing line that moves down the page  as a user scrolls. I am using Wordpress, and I have tried nothing short of 100 different ways and about 500 page revisions to get this to work. I have tried doing a SVG path (draw scroll), and lots of other methods. I finally have a sort of working solution that uses a large background image, and then CSS to manipulate the line to appear to grow as the page is scrolled.

Here is my code, and the page it is used on. The problem is, although my solution works - it does not show on mobile. It does show when the browser window is squeezed in, but not on actual mobile - which makes me think something in my code is conflicting with true mobile-based OS. I have tried it in Chrome and Safari with no luck. Please help or if feeling up to a challenge - maybe an alternative way to make this seeming small but really difficult feature come to life.

Here is a link to my page where implemented: https://marydbourbon.com/her-story-timeline

```js
// detect touch 
if (("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
  document.documentElement.className += " touch";
}



! function(t, e) {
  "object" == typeof exports && "object" == typeof module ? module.exports = e() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define([], e) : "object" == typeof exports ? exports.inView = e() : t.inView = e()
}(this, function() {
  return function(t) {
    function e(r) {
      if (n[r]) return n[r].exports;
      var i = n[r] = {
        exports: {},
        id: r,
        loaded: !1
      };
      return t[r].call(i.exports, i, i.exports, e), i.loaded = !0, i.exports
    }
    var n = {};
    return e.m = t, e.c = n, e.p = "", e(0)
  }([function(t, e, n) {
    "use strict";

    function r(t) {
      return t && t.__esModule ? t : {
        "default": t
      }
    }
    var i = n(2),
      o = r(i);
    t.exports = o["default"]
  }, function(t, e) {
    function n(t) {
      var e = typeof t;
      return null != t && ("object" == e || "function" == e)
    }
    t.exports = n
  }, function(t, e, n) {
    "use strict";

    function r(t) {
      return t && t.__esModule ? t : {
        "default": t
      }
    }
    Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
      value: !0
    });
    var i = n(9),
      o = r(i),
      u = n(3),
      f = r(u),
      s = n(4),
      c = function() {
        if ("undefined" != typeof window) {
          var t = 100,
            e = ["scroll", "resize", "load"],
            n = {
              history: []
            },
            r = {
              offset: {},
              threshold: 0,
              test: s.inViewport
            },
            i = (0, o["default"])(function() {
              n.history.forEach(function(t) {
                n[t].check()
              })
            }, t);
          e.forEach(function(t) {
            return addEventListener(t, i)
          }), window.MutationObserver && addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            new MutationObserver(i).observe(document.body, {
              attributes: !0,
              childList: !0,
              subtree: !0
            })
          });
          var u = function(t) {
            if ("string" == typeof t) {
              var e = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(t));
              return n.history.indexOf(t) > -1 ? n[t].elements = e : (n[t] = (0, f["default"])(e, r), n.history.push(t)), n[t]
            }
          };
          return u.offset = function(t) {
            if (void 0 === t) return r.offset;
            var e = function(t) {
              return "number" == typeof t
            };
            return ["top", "right", "bottom", "left"].forEach(e(t) ? function(e) {
              return r.offset[e] = t
            } : function(n) {
              return e(t[n]) ? r.offset[n] = t[n] : null
            }), r.offset
          }, u.threshold = function(t) {
            return "number" == typeof t && t >= 0 && t <= 1 ? r.threshold = t : r.threshold
          }, u.test = function(t) {
            return "function" == typeof t ? r.test = t : r.test
          }, u.is = function(t) {
            return r.test(t, r)
          }, u.offset(0), u
        }
      };
    e["default"] = c()
  }, function(t, e) {
    "use strict";

    function n(t, e) {
      if (!(t instanceof e)) throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")
    }
    Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
      value: !0
    });
    var r = function() {
        function t(t, e) {
          for (var n = 0; n < e.length; n++) {
            var r = e[n];
            r.enumerable = r.enumerable || !1, r.configurable = !0, "value" in r && (r.writable = !0), Object.defineProperty(t, r.key, r)
          }
        }
        return function(e, n, r) {
          return n && t(e.prototype, n), r && t(e, r), e
        }
      }(),
      i = function() {
        function t(e, r) {
          n(this, t), this.options = r, this.elements = e, this.current = [], this.handlers = {
            enter: [],
            exit: []
          }, this.singles = {
            enter: [],
            exit: []
          }
        }
        return r(t, [{
          key: "check",
          value: function() {
            var t = this;
            return this.elements.forEach(function(e) {
              var n = t.options.test(e, t.options),
                r = t.current.indexOf(e),
                i = r > -1,
                o = n && !i,
                u = !n && i;
              o && (t.current.push(e), t.emit("enter", e)), u && (t.current.splice(r, 1), t.emit("exit", e))
            }), this
          }
        }, {
          key: "on",
          value: function(t, e) {
            return this.handlers[t].push(e), this
          }
        }, {
          key: "once",
          value: function(t, e) {
            return this.singles[t].unshift(e), this
          }
        }, {
          key: "emit",
          value: function(t, e) {
            for (; this.singles[t].length;) this.singles[t].pop()(e);
            for (var n = this.handlers[t].length; --n > -1;) this.handlers[t][n](e);
            return this
          }
        }]), t
      }();
    e["default"] = function(t, e) {
      return new i(t, e)
    }
  }, function(t, e) {
    "use strict";

    function n(t, e) {
      var n = t.getBoundingClientRect(),
        r = n.top,
        i = n.right,
        o = n.bottom,
        u = n.left,
        f = n.width,
        s = n.height,
        c = {
          t: o,
          r: window.innerWidth - u,
          b: window.innerHeight - r,
          l: i
        },
        a = {
          x: e.threshold * f,
          y: e.threshold * s
        };
      return c.t > e.offset.top + a.y && c.r > e.offset.right + a.x && c.b > e.offset.bottom + a.y && c.l > e.offset.left + a.x
    }
    Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
      value: !0
    }), e.inViewport = n
  }, function(t, e) {
    (function(e) {
      var n = "object" == typeof e && e && e.Object === Object && e;
      t.exports = n
    }).call(e, function() {
      return this
    }())
  }, function(t, e, n) {
    var r = n(5),
      i = "object" == typeof self && self && self.Object === Object && self,
      o = r || i || Function("return this")();
    t.exports = o
  }, function(t, e, n) {
    function r(t, e, n) {
      function r(e) {
        var n = x,
          r = m;
        return x = m = void 0, E = e, w = t.apply(r, n)
      }

      function a(t) {
        return E = t, j = setTimeout(h, e), M ? r(t) : w
      }

      function l(t) {
        var n = t - O,
          r = t - E,
          i = e - n;
        return _ ? c(i, g - r) : i
      }

      function d(t) {
        var n = t - O,
          r = t - E;
        return void 0 === O || n >= e || n < 0 || _ && r >= g
      }

      function h() {
        var t = o();
        return d(t) ? p(t) : void(j = setTimeout(h, l(t)))
      }

      function p(t) {
        return j = void 0, T && x ? r(t) : (x = m = void 0, w)
      }

      function v() {
        void 0 !== j && clearTimeout(j), E = 0, x = O = m = j = void 0
      }

      function y() {
        return void 0 === j ? w : p(o())
      }

      function b() {
        var t = o(),
          n = d(t);
        if (x = arguments, m = this, O = t, n) {
          if (void 0 === j) return a(O);
          if (_) return j = setTimeout(h, e), r(O)
        }
        return void 0 === j && (j = setTimeout(h, e)), w
      }
      var x, m, g, w, j, O, E = 0,
        M = !1,
        _ = !1,
        T = !0;
      if ("function" != typeof t) throw new TypeError(f);
      return e = u(e) || 0, i(n) && (M = !!n.leading, _ = "maxWait" in n, g = _ ? s(u(n.maxWait) || 0, e) : g, T = "trailing" in n ? !!n.trailing : T), b.cancel = v, b.flush = y, b
    }
    var i = n(1),
      o = n(8),
      u = n(10),
      f = "Expected a function",
      s = Math.max,
      c = Math.min;
    t.exports = r
  }, function(t, e, n) {
    var r = n(6),
      i = function() {
        return r.Date.now()
      };
    t.exports = i
  }, function(t, e, n) {
    function r(t, e, n) {
      var r = !0,
        f = !0;
      if ("function" != typeof t) throw new TypeError(u);
      return o(n) && (r = "leading" in n ? !!n.leading : r, f = "trailing" in n ? !!n.trailing : f), i(t, e, {
        leading: r,
        maxWait: e,
        trailing: f
      })
    }
    var i = n(7),
      o = n(1),
      u = "Expected a function";
    t.exports = r
  }, function(t, e) {
    function n(t) {
      return t
    }
    t.exports = n
  }])
});

inView('.panel').on('enter', function(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 1;
}).on('exit', function(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0.5;
});
//inView.offset(100);
inView.threshold(0.3);
```

```css
.join2 {
  height: 100vh;
  height: calc(60vh + 1px);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 3px;
  /* greater than 1px for edge bug*/
  margin: 0px auto;
  z-index: 200;
  background: url(https://marydbourbon.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/css-bg.png) no-repeat fixed 50%;
  background-size: 3px 50vh;
  /*transform:translateX(50%); remove as creates stacking context for fixed positioned image*/
}

.touch .join {
  background-attachment: scroll
}
```

```html
<div class="join2"> </div>
```

I have tried everything. Not being dramatic - I was reluctant to even ask for help without first exhausting every conceivable fiber of my capability. I am coming up short. Please help!

Comment: Is that what you need but to appear vertically: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp

Comment: Sort of. I will be placing the vertical line in content blocks/containers between existing content blocks. It is a way to "lead" them down the page in timeline type of style. So, I need a line that "stays" in the container, does not appear until scroll, and retracts once user scrolls back up. The main issue I also run into is with multiple instances of anything I have tried do not start/stop as each new screen scroll position is loaded. For instance, with using SVG paths, the first one worked...but then down the page, all others were already fully expanded before user got there.

Comment: The strangest thing - I can see the line on a mobile/browser mobile emulator for iPhone, Android, etc. - but it does not show on an actual device. Frustrating!

Comment: So, i figured out the issue of why it is not showing on iPhone mobile (it DOES show on Android devices) - it is the CSS after the image "background: url(https://marydbourbon.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/css-bg.png) no-repeat fixed 50%;" - apparently Apple does not support "fixed". -so what to do? Please help!!

Comment: Could this be edited to still be a fixed background for the same effect without somehow using a fixed background? I have read many places (now after the fact), that mobile (esp. IOs) does not support "fixed" BG images. :(